# how to make text vertically centered in wxStaticText?

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

How can I make the text vertically centered in wxStaticText (single line) in cpp Windows using WxWidget?

For example if I increase the height of wxStaticText (single line) with default font size, the text is align at top, I want it to be at center vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think text controls support vertical text alignment styles. As far as I know, if you want to create a text control where the text is vertically centered, the only way is to fake it.

This can be done by creating a borderless text control and then center that text control inside another window whose only purpose is to look like the border of the text control

```
wxPanel* pseudoText = new wxPanel(<parent>, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition,
                                  wxDefaultSize,
                                  wxBORDER_THEME|wxTAB_TRAVERSAL);
wxTextCtrl* text = new wxTextCtrl(pseudoText, wxID_ANY, wxString(),
                                  wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize,
                                  wxTE_CENTRE|wxBORDER_NONE);
pseudoText->SetBackgroundColour(text->GetBackgroundColour());

wxBoxSizer* szr = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
szr->AddStretchSpacer();
szr->Add(text, wxSizerFlags().Expand());
szr->AddStretchSpacer();
pseudoText->SetSizer(szr);
```

On windows, this mostly looks like a text control with vertically centered text:

[image]

The border is slightly wrong, but I think this is the best that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Your wxStaticText should be contained in a sizer. If it's not then I recommend you read up about sizers and start using them. There are a few good (free and commercial) UI editors out there that makes using them pretty easy.

wxStaticText itself only has options to center the text horizontally (probably a restriction of the underlying OS), but when you add the wxStaticText control to a sizer, you can specify any alignment (CENTER_VERTICALLY, CENTER_HORIZONTALLY etc...).

Example:

```
wxBoxSizer *mysizer=new wxBoxSizer...
wxStaticText *sometext=new wxStaticText...

mysizer->Add(sometext, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

It is important, that the sizer itself fills the entire space you want to vertically center the text in. Have a look at the wxWidgets sizer samples. You need to get a basic understanding of how sizers work.

Comment: Still not working i used following code:
`wxBoxSizer* topsizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
wxTextCtrl* NameText = new wxTextCtrl(p, wxID_ANY, "", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(250, 30));
topsizer->Add(NameText, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL);`

Comment: Try adding stretchable spacers on both sides of the text control.  Like so `...topsizer->AddStretchSpacer(1); topsizer->Add(NameText, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL); topsizer->AddStretchSpacer(1);...` The 2 spacers on either side should push the text control to the center.

Comment: @Klaffy, did you get any kind of assert? or it just doesn't align? what's your wxWidgets version?

Comment: The answer should add that the sizer must itself have enough space for the the static text to be centred. If it's just big enough for the static text size height, nothing is going to happen.

Comment: @NewPagodi i am not trying to center the widget, but i am trying to center the text vertically inside the text control, because when i increase the height of text control, the text is align at top vertically.

Comment: @Igor yes it says, Vertical alignment flags are ignored in vertical sizers.